# Purpose of color resolution bits in a gif

Tags: image

I've dissected a gif image and here is the data in the header:
['G', 'I', 'F', '8', '9', 'a', '^', '\x01', '^', '\x01', '\x87', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x01', '\x00', '\x00', '\x01']

The 0x87 represents the flag byte in the gif.  Converting this to binary results in 0b10000111.

I'm using http://www.matthewflickinger.com/lab/whatsinagif/bits_and_bytes.asp as a reference.

So, according that to that website, the gif has a (zero + 1) colour resolution (2 possible colours, even though the image has many more).  I tried editing this number and it didn't seem to change anything.  Can someone explain the purpose of the colour resolution bits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can edit it without harm because it's not needed to decode the data - all it does is describe the "source" of the data (the last three bits in that byte are what apply to this particular image).

the standard itself http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt (page 9) says:

> This value represents the size of the entire palette from which the
>   colors in the graphic were selected, not the number of colors actually
>   used in the graphic.

and then goes on to add:

> This value should be set to indicate the richness of the original
>   palette, even if not every color from the whole palette is available
>   on the source machine.

so it looks like even the original authors didn't have much idea for how it would be used.  and since it's not really useful, i imagine it's not set correctly by some software.

[the only use i can see is that if this value were larger than the actual colour depth used you could add a caption/popup saying "the original image was better than this".]